Tyrus websockets are getting disconnected after being idle. Need default timeout values to fix this
I am using standalone tyrus websocket server with tyrus grizzly container. version 1.9
The websockets are getting disconnected on some systems after some timeout. I am trying to find the reason why it is getting disconnected only in some systems and not getting disconnected in others. which property manages this timeout?
I know that this can be fixed using a heartbeat mechanism. But I need to arrive at the optimal time for sending the heartbeat. for this, But I would like to understand why the timeout is not consistent in each systems.
Is there any property I can set to ensure the session keep alive timeout is same in all systems.
I tried reading the documentation to understand the default keepalive timeout for the websocket sessions. It doesn't seem to follow the OS properties atleast in windows, for tcp keepalive timeout.
I looked through the source code to see if there are any properties that can be set to ensure the timeout is same in all systems.

You can set the timeout on a Session
